What is the usage for constructs like "men at work", "children at play", etc
One sometimes sees road warning signs cautioning of "men [sic] at work" or "children at play".  The meaning is clear, it's the same as "men working" or "children playing".  Other examples of this construct are "ships at sail", "bodies at rest", "player at bat", "nations at war" and (maybe) "soldiers at attention".
It's not easy to find others.  Invented examples that follow the same pattern (e.g. "professors at lecture", "linguists at argue") sound awful.  It's odd that "bodies at motion" sounds wrong, as has to be "bodies in motion".  One can freely alter the noun: "women/people/humans/robots at work" are all fine.  Changing the verb is not okay.
How did this construct get into the language?  Perhaps it imitates a structure from some parent language?  Was it perhaps more widely used before, so that only the frozen examples remain acceptable (hard to explain the baseball example, I doubt the Anglo Saxons had it.)  Why can we change the noun freely, but not the verb.

I have a feeling it comes from French. I think there are many French idioms that use à similarly.

Why do you find this a problem?  'Men at work' is a recognisable phrase, which can fit into a sentence.  For example, " the phrase 'Men at work' on road signs is sexist".  But its meaning is obvious.  It is a sentence fragment.  But there is a known convention (which saves drivers the dangerous distraction of reading the longer full sentence "There are men at work here" or "men are at work here".  However, this convention may not be covered by grammar books, other, perhaps, than phrase books for foreign visitors.

I am trying to account for why this construct appears frozen.  You can substitute almost any noun in, e.g. "women/people/humans/robots at work" but not any verb.

Apologies for the sexism in "men at work", but that is the way the sign appears.  I'm just citing data that I observe.

'Ships at anchor' almost certainly involves the noun rather than the verb 'anchor'.  ('At leisure' is semantically different.) 'Anchored ships' is grammatical but sounds nowhere near as attractive. Aren't you really examining the metaphorical scope of the PP [N₁s] 'at N₂'?

ships at sail, not ships at anchor

Signs often adopt an abbreviated syntax, given to quickly informing passersby of what is going on. Context plus the phrase "men at work" is enough to convey that one should drive more slowly by a work site. The phrase may be older than its use on modern road signs; for instance, the 1941 Graham Greene short story "Men at Work" (published in the New Yorker) sends up the trivial work of men at a book committee, in a way that only works if the phrase is already understood. In this answer I trace early documented uses of the phrase.
In short, the phrase has been used for several hundred years to refer to laborers.
19th Century Use: Bureaucratic Convenience
"Men at work" tended to be used in labor studies in the 19th and early 20th century. As English-speaking countries sought to use data to better understand labor and economics, "men at work" was a convenient moniker for currently employed workers. For instance, in an 1877 edition of the Annual Report of the Department of Mines, New South Wales (Google Books ), the phrase "men at work" is repeatedly used to add up the men working in each site: two men at work, three men at work, and so on. Here is one example showing the abbreviated reporting:

Enterprise Reef.--Pettit and party.-- Four men at work; vein 2 feet wide; 223 tons of stone crushe[d] in 1878, yielding 363 ozs. 12 dwts; worked by whip and horse.

A less abbreviated example occurs in the 1871 report Manchester at Work by William Fletcher (Google Books), again demonstrating the count use of the phrase:

We had five hundred and fourteen men at work last week, against two less the week before, and four hundred and sixty men for the week before, against four hundred and thirty-five in the previous week; but masons form the chief bulk of our men.

Earlier Use: What You Call a Worker
I was surprised to find the phrase used earlier than these bureaucratic reports.
For example, the 1850 Annals of Philadelphia by John Watson (Google Books feature the phrase several times to describe people acting out work as part of a July 4th, 1788 procession celebrating the adoption of the Constitution as well as the signing of the Declaration of Independence:

A frame drawn by four horses, eighteen feet long, contained the frame of the Union's barge, and men at work at the same. The boatbuilders followed, with a flag

As a generic phrase for a working man, the phrase can be found even in the 17th century, like in the 1652 text Cosmographie by Peter Heylyn (EEBO):

In former times esteemed a rich and wealthy Countrey, stored with all sorts of fruits, and so abounding in Silver Mines, that when the Romans were Lords of it, they kept continually 400 men at work, and received 2500 Drachmas of daily profit: now for the most part barren, and but ill inhabited.

Origin: Man at Arms?
This earlier usage makes me guess that the phrase is rather similar in formation if not origin to man at arms, that is, a professional soldier. That usage comes from the 16th century and is likely influenced by the Old French homme à armes (modern French might prefer homme d'armes, man of arms) or Anglo-Norman genz as armes (OED). If the usage existed for men who fight, then the usage could exist for other broad groupings of people, like man at law (EEBO) or, as we're seeing, man at work, as a broad descriptor for laborer.
Another alternative is that the phrase was first a part of a larger phrasing where kept or similar verbs were modified by at work. The 1652 example above follows that pattern: where were men kept? At work. Over time and habitual usage, men at work became idiomatic even without the verb.
Either way, what modern signs inherit is older than modern labor.
